# How to move files from one s3 to another recursively?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

i have a lambda to copy files (sample code below) , once files are copied , i delete from source. is there a way to move files instead and also do it recursively, to maintain folder or prefix in s3?

```
import json
import boto3
s3_client=boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket_name=event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_name=event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    destination_bucket_name='gfg-destination-bucket'
    copy_object={'Bucket':source_bucket_name,'Key':file_name}
    s3_client.copy_object(CopySource=copy_object,Bucket=destination_bucket_name,Key=file_name)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Success')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method for moving file from source S3 bucket to Destination S3 Bucket.

So you have to Copy file then delete from source

import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# TODO implement

```
SOURCE_BUCKET='source-test-file'
DESTINATION_BUCKET='destiation-test-file'

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(SOURCE_BUCKET)
dest_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(DESTINATION_BUCKET)

#count = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=SOURCE_BUCKET)
count = bucket.objects.all()

#count total files in bucket

totalCount = 0

print('result :',len(list(count)))

length = len(list(count))

if (length==0):

    print('result :',len(list(count)))
    print("bucket is empety")

else:
    
    print("bucket is not empety")
    
    for object in bucket.objects.all():
        print("print :",object.key)
        key1 = object.key
        sourceObject = { 'Bucket' : 'source-test-file', 'Key': object.key}
        destObject = { 'Bucket' : 'destiation-test-file', 'Key': object.key}
        s3_resource.meta.client.copy(sourceObject, 'destiation-test-file',key1)
        #Delete the File After Copying It to the Target Directory
        s3_resource.Object('sourceObject','*.txt').delete()
    
        
    totalCount += 1

    print("file Moved")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).